# Handle nested Exceptions in delete hook & Ignore DrupalKernel Exception handler

Tags: 8, hooks

I have functionality that checks if entities can be deleted or not.
These entities are vast and most of them are linked together with EntityReference fields.

Now in some cases I want to check if an entity can be deleted, and that all depends on the existence of related entities.

Probably better to explain with an example.

I have entities related like this:

```
Entity1
└── Entity2
    └── Entity3
```

(So Entity3, has en entity reference field to Entity2, and Entity2 has one to 1).

**The rules:**

1. If Entity1 has entities of type Entity2 related, automatically delete all related entities of type Entity2.
2. If Entity2 has entities of type Entity3 related, The entity of type Entity2 cannot be deleted. And thus if the delete happens through a cascading delete from Entity1, that Entity cannot be deleted.

The code is quite a lot more complicated, but the gist of it is:

1. I added a `delete` hook on Entity1, that queries all the related 
   Entity2 records and deletes them.

```php
    function hook_entity_entity1_delete($entity)
    {
      try {
        $connection = \Drupal::database();
        $transaction = $connection->startTransaction();
        // Query entity2 entities and delete them
      } catch(\Throwable $t) {
        $transaction->rollback();
        throw $t;
      }
    }
```

2. I added a `predelete` hook on Entity2, that queries all the related Entity3 records, and if records are found. Throw an Exception.

```php
    function hook_entity_entity2_predelete($entity)
    {
      // Query entity3 records and if found:
      throw EntityHasRelatedRecordsException();
    }
```

This all works under perfect circumstances, however, in case someone that uses my module writes a custom `predelete` hook for Entity3. And does something that causes an unhandled exception. The unhandled exception is catched by the default Drupal Exception handler defined in [DrupalKernel.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core%2Flib%2FDrupal%2FCore%2FDrupalKernel.php#L1041) and enters the exception handler [here in bootstrap.inc](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core%2Fincludes%2Fbootstrap.inc#L609)

Now Drupal does not throw that exception again. And because of that the code can never enter the `catch` on `hook_entity_entity1_delete`. And my transaction gets commited to the database. So the Entity1 is deleted, but all related Entity2 and Entity3 records stay in the database.

How can I make sure my logic is safe for custom implementation that might contain unhandled exceptions or runtime errors? 
Is there a way of defining my own exception handler?

Comment: There is an issue on Drupal.org about this, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2521852

Comment: It's hard to protect someone adding a predelete hook with a syntax error causing a fatal exception. But you can catch non fatal exceptions, not handled in a try/catch block, in a kernel.exception subscriber, which should be OK for most things coming up in production.

Comment: @Jdrupal I came across this issue, but it seems to be Closed/Fixed while not having a solution. Or am I seeing it wrong?

Comment: @4k4 this seems interesting. I can live with ignoring errors. As long as I can catch Exceptions I'm happy. Do you have an example how to implement an Exception subscriber?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235906/handle-database-connection-exception-via-custom-handler

Comment: Cheers for that!