# Database Rollback Transaction?

Tags: 8, database

I have a multi database site, when I save my content type it is added in both the **Laravel** side database and the default **Drupal** database.
Now most of my code is in try catch and it does not save data in Laravel db in case of catch but it does save the content types or nodes in the Drupal db hence they show up in my views. How do I stop this in case any error occurs while saving the content type ?
eg ;

```
try {

        if (!empty($rec)) {
            $db->update('xyz')->fields([
                'type' => $type,
                'logo' => $img_url,
                'link' => $redirect_url,
                'status_id' => $form_state->getValue('field_status')[0]['value'],
                'site_id' => $form_state->getValue('field_site')[0]['target_id'],
                'updated_at' => $currentDateTime,
            ])->condition('id', $rec['id'])
                ->execute();
            $message = 'Content has been updated successfully to the job portal.';
            \Drupal::messenger()->deleteAll();
            \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($message);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //log the exception to watchdog.
        $message = 'Something went wrong to save content in job portal';
        \Drupal::messenger()->deleteAll();
        \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t($message));
        \Drupal::logger('Save-Awards and Certificates')
            ->error($e->getMessage());
    }
    \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('default');
```

Comment: Just to clarify the question, you don't want to save the nodes to Drupal in case there is an error saving to Laravel?

Comment: You can check this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223140/prevent-node-from-being-saved-in-hook-node-presave

Comment: It's unclear where the code is placed, but assuming it is in a hook presave hook. If you did not catch the exception or did throw a new exception, then the node wouldn't be saved, because on Drupal side an entity save operation is by default enclosed in a transaction which is rolled back in case of an error.

Comment: BTW if you only want to log and display the error message then you can do this in an exception event subscriber, you don't need to catch the exception here.