# How to catch the payload for bad POST requests with JSON:API?

Tags: 9, log-messages

When POSTing to JSON:API with invalid parameters, `UnprocessableHttpEntityException` is thrown.

However, in the logs, this exception does not contain the invalid payload that caused the exception.  How can I log the bad payload with the exception?

In a custom module, I created **MymoduleExceptionSubscriber.php**::

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

class MymoduleExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {   
  public function onException(ExceptionEvent $event): void {
    $exception = $event
      ->getThrowable();
    $original_exception = $this->getOriginalException($exception);

    if ($original_exception instanceof UnprocessableHttpEntityException) {
        $this->logger->get('custom_jsonapi_exception')->error($this->getErrorMessage($original_exception));
      }
  }

  /**
   * Generate a useful error message to log an exception.
   *
   * @param \Exception $exception
   *   The exception to generate an error message for.
   *
   * @return string
   *   The generated error message.
   */
  private function getErrorMessage(\Exception $exception): string {
    $exception_class = get_class($exception);
    $violations = '';
    if(method_exists($exception, 'getViolations')) {
      $violations = '<br>Violations' . $exception->getViolations();
    }
    return "Class: $exception_class <br>Message: " .
      $exception->getMessage() .
      $violations .
      '<br>File: ' .
      $exception->getFile() .
      '<br>Line number: ' .
      $exception->getLine() .
      '<br>Stack trace:<br>' .
      $exception->getTraceAsString();
  }

  /**
   * Drupal may catch exceptions for us and rethrow them. This undoes that.
   *
   * More info: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/311935.
   *
   * @param \Throwable $exception
   *   The exception to drill into.
   *
   * @return \Throwable
   *   The original (first) exception.
   */
  private function getOriginalException(\Throwable $exception): \Throwable {
    $original_exception = $exception;
    while ($original_exception->getPrevious()) {
      $original_exception = $original_exception->getPrevious();
    }
    return $original_exception;
  }

}
```

This allows me to catch the exception and, by logging `getViolations()`, get information on which field(s) caused the `UnprocessableHttpEntityException`.  However, knowing which fields failed to validate is only half the problem-- the other half is checking what the bad input in the payload was.

How can I log such info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the payload get the request referenced in the event:

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
$body = Json::decode($request->getContent());
$data = $body['data'];
```